# Devolver un List Multidimensional una función y carga del List

Tags: c#

Estoy creando una función en c# para web en la que deseo que devuelva dos campos para cargar un listbox con value y text (cosa que tengo que ver como se hace, pero eso es un problema futuro) El caso es que no se como hacer la función. Os pego el código que tengo hecho para que lo veáis y me indiquéis,por favor, que está mal hecho y como rehacerlo:

```
public List<List<string>> listadoViajes(string prefixText) /*public static List<string> listadoViajes(string prefixText)*/
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexion"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT (CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(Nombre)) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(Apellidos)) AS VARCHAR(150))) Usuario, idUsuarioAgencia
                                                    FROM tbl_UsuarioAgencia
                                                    WHERE idAgencia = 1 AND idUsuarioAgencia <> 0
                                                     AND (Nombre LIKE '%'+@param+'%' OR Apellidos LIKE '%'+@param+'%' OR usr LIKE '%'+@param+'%')"))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param", prefixText);

                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();

                    var Listado = new List<(int idUsuarioAgencia, string Usuario)>();

                    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (sdr.Read())
                        Listado.Add(sdr["idUsuarioAgencia"], sdr["Usuario"].ToString());
                    con.Close();
                    return Listado;
                }
            }
        }
```

Los errores me dan en las siguientes partes del código (y además mis dudas):
1.- Declaración de la variable: No se si en la declaración tengo que hacer que sea "List<List>" indicando que lo que me ha devolver es una variable de dos campos
2.- Carga de datos: Me falla en la línea "Listado.Add(sdr["idUsuarioAgencia"], sdr["Usuario"].ToString());" en la palabra Add, ya que no se como cargar la lista.
3.- Devolución de resultado: Devuelvo "Listado" y ahí falla porque en la declaración de la variable le digo que es bidimensional y, sin embargo, le devuelvo un List sólamente ¿Qué he de hacer aquí?

Gracias

Comment: Si quieres hacerlo con un List puedes crear un objeto con 2 propiedades String y entonces la List la creas para que contenga ese objeto. Sino tambien puedes usar un Dictionary, que tambien te serviria.

Comment: La mejor opción a priori es crear una clase `Usuario` con dos propiedades, una int para el id y otra string para el nombre. Despues, simplemente el metodo devolvera un `List<Usuario>`. De esta manera, tambien solucionarás el problema futuro al cargar el `ListBox`, dado que ya tendrás los valores por separado.

Comment: Yo cargaría todo en un datatable que para eso estan

Comment: He creado la función como un Dictionary<int, string>, he creado este código que me funciona:

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tú tienes se llama [Tuplas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples), es una especie de estructura (un struct) que se puede crear rápidamente. Esto fue incluido en .net hace solo un par de años. La idea era resolver el problema que tienes tú, que es almacenar más de un valor en una lista (o retornar más de un valor), para lo cual antes se debía crear una clase solo para hacer ese retorno.

Como se declara una tupla:

Con nombres anonimos

- `(int, string) nombre = (1,"hola");`

Con nombres

- `(int edad, string nombre) persona = (12,"juan");`
- Aunque se llama tupla puede tener n valores
- `(int edad, string nombre, string apellido, Unaclase algo) = (12,"juan", "peres", new UnaCLase);`

En tu caso, te faltan los paréntesis:

`Listado.Add(  ( sdr["idUsuarioAgencia"], sdr["Usuario"].ToString() )  );`

Además en la declaración de la función debes poner el retorno real

```
public List<(int idUsuarioAgencia, string Usuario)> listadoViajes(string prefixText)
{
   //ETC
   return Listado;
}
```

Ejemplo de imprimir valores

```
            foreach(var item in Listado) {
                Console.WriteLine(item.idUsuarioAgencia);
                Console.WriteLine(item.Usuario);
            }
```

Si te fijas es igual a que hubiera colocado una lista de objetos.

Comment: Por aclarar una cosa, las tuplas si no recuerdo mal se introdujeron en el [net framework 4.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms171868(v=vs.100)#tuples)..de eso hace un poco mas de un par de años ;)

Comment: @Pikoh En la 4.7 según el mismo link que puse, es decir el 2017 (a mí me parecía ayer). Creo que el link que tu pusiste se refiere a las tuplas que se creaban de esta manera Tuple<T1,T2> = Tuple.Create(..). Es decir sin la sintaxis de paréntesis

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. Tras leer la documentación, tu te refieres a [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/System.ValueTuple?view=netframework-4.7) que son basicamente tuplas en tiempo de ejecución. Ahora si, aclarado el tema :)

Comment: Pero yo llamo la función del siguiente modo:

ListaUsuarios.AddRange(objComUsuario.listadoViajes(cadena));             

foreach (var usuario in ListaUsuarios)
{
      System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(usuario.ToString());      
}
Pero el AddRange me da error ¿Como evito este error?

Comment: @JesúsPrieto No entiendo, que pasa con eso???

Answer (score 0):

Prueba cambiando un poco tu código con este:

```
var Listado = new List<List<string>>();

                    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (sdr.Read()){
                        List<string> ListPares= new List<string>();
                        ListPares.Add(sdr["idUsuarioAgencia"].ToString()??"");
                        ListPares.Add(sdr["Usuario"].ToString()??"");
                        Listado.Add(ListPares);
                    }
```

Esto es para resolver el problema que planteas pero no te lo recomiendo, porque crear una lista solo para dos valores es sospechoso de mala practica.
**Te recomiendo que cargues los datos en un DataTable con ayuda de un SqlAdapter.**

```
                var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                var dt =new Datatable();      
                da.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: Sin animo de entrar en discusiones, los DataTables fueron una herramienta importante en su momento, pero yo hoy en dia no se les recomendaría a nadie. De hecho, solucionar los problemas de los DataSets/DataTables etc probablemente fue una de las motivaciones de los ORM como EntityFramework. [Aqui](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/aa479317(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) puedes leer un articulo sobre el tema ya del año 2011. Un saludo